# Access function pointers outside of the instance

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a class as outlined below:

```
class InputReader 
{  
public:
  typedef void (*handler)(std::string, int);
  static void errorHandler(std::string error, int severity); //Supplies a default error handler
  static void warningHandler(std::string error, int severity); //Supplies a default warning handler
  handler errorH;
  handler warningH;

  InputReader(std::string pwd = "", handler eHandler = errorHandler, handler wHandler = warningHandler);

  bool readFile(std::string filename);
  std::vector<first> mesh;
  //other irrelevant objects that need to be read into
};
```

`first` is a struct:

```
struct first
{
  std::string filename;
  double scale;
};
```

With [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck)'s help I have:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& file, first& obj) 
{
  std::string symbol;
  while(file >> symbol) 
  {
    if (symbol[0] == '#') 
    {
      std::getline(file, symbol);
    } 
    else if (symbol == FIRSTTAGEND) 
    {
      break;
    }
    else if (symbol == FILEPATH) 
    {
      if (!(file >> '=' >> obj.filename))
        std::cerr << symbol << " is incorrectly formatted"; //This needs to use errorH
    } 
    else if (symbol == SCALE) 
    {
      if (! (file >> '=' >> obj.scale) )
        std::cerr << symbol << " is incorrectly formatted"; //This needs to use errorH
    } 
    else 
    { //not a member: failure
      std::cerr << symbol << " is not a member of first";
      file.setstate(file.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit);
      break;
    }
  }
  return file;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& file, InputReader& obj) 
{
  std::string symbol;
  while(file >> symbol) 
  {
    if (symbol[0] == '#') 
    {
      std::getline(file, symbol);
    } 
    else if (symbol == FIRSTTAGBEG) 
    {
      first t;
      if (file >> t)
        obj.mesh.push_back(t);
    } 
    else 
    {
      obj.errorH(symbol + " is not a member of the input reader.", 1);
      file.setstate(file.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit);
    }
  }
  return file;
}

bool InputReader::readFile(std::string filename)
{
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open(filename.c_str());
  infile >> *this;
  return true;
}
```

`errorH` gets set upon construction of the InputReader object. It can be provided by the user of the class, otherwise, it uses the default ones I provide. The only problem is that I can't access `errorH` when `first` is being read into. How can I solve this?

Problem constraints: External libraries are not allowed. C++11/C++OX is not allowed.

Comment: Can't you pass a reference to the owning InputReader to First during construction? Also, make it a friend of InputReader and then you can call the error handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You naturally have few options:

1. Do not use `>>` operator and create a function that does the same but accepts three arguments - an input stream, a `first` object and an input reader object.
2. Define operator `>>` that accepts a tuple of `first` and `InputReader` as a second argument (i.e. a pair of pointers). For example: `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& file, std::pair<first *, InputReader *> & obj)`.

You can extend this list indefinitely as long as you have a good imagination.

Hope it helps.

***UPDATE:***

Here goes some simple example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct first {
    std::string filename;
    double scale;
};

class InputReader {
  public:
    typedef void (*handler)(const std::string &, int);

    InputReader(const std::string & pwd = std::string(),
                handler eHandler = errorHandler,
                handler wHandler = warningHandler);

    bool readFile(const std::string & filename);

    static void errorHandler(const std::string & error, int severity);
    static void warningHandler(const std::string & error, int severity);

    handler errorH;
    handler warningH;
    first firstobj;
    std::vector<first> mesh;
};

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & file,
                            std::pair<first, InputReader *> & obj)
{
    std::string symbol;
    while (file >> symbol) {
        if (symbol[0] == '#') {
            std::getline(file, symbol);
        } else if (symbol == "FIRSTTAGEND") {
            break;
        } else if (symbol == "FILEPATH") {
            if (!(file >> obj.first.filename))
                obj.second->errorHandler(symbol + " is incorrectly formatted",
                                         1);
        } else if (symbol == "SCALE") {
            if (!(file >> obj.first.scale))
                obj.second->errorHandler(symbol + " is incorrectly formatted",
                                         1);
        } else { //not a member: failure
            std::cerr << symbol << " is not a member of first";
            file.setstate(file.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit);
            break;
        }
    }
    return file;
}

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & file, InputReader & obj)
{
    std::string symbol;

    while (file >> symbol) {
        if (symbol[0] == '#') {
            std::getline(file, symbol);
        } else if (symbol == "FIRSTTAGBEG") {
            std::pair<first, InputReader *> t(first(), &obj);
            if (file >> t)
                obj.mesh.push_back(t.first);
        } else {
            obj.errorH(symbol + " is not a member of the input reader.", 1);
            file.setstate(file.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit);
        }
    }
    return file;
}

bool InputReader::readFile(const std::string & filename)
{
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename.c_str());
    infile >> *this;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you would then modify the "first" operator>> for #2?

Comment: Hm, that seems to be obvious - I've provided an example signature. Then just refer to `file` as `obj.first` and to input reader as `obj.second`...

Comment: @Vlad A little background as to why I ask for "obvious details": My original code that this will be replacing is riddled with bugs and it keeps breaking. I'm trying to get it right the first time, this time.

Comment: Vlad, please include an example. I can't for the life of me get it working.

Comment: @Drise: I have a strong feeling that you would benefit from reading some C++ book. Anyways, I've added some example for you.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I struggled with pair 1) because I have worked very little with them, and 2) because std::make_pair would not work using it JIT.

Comment: I [and others in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4595712#4595712) dislike the idea of using `pair` in this way.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I am with you on that one.

Answer (score 2):

Vlad gives an interesting idea, but I'm not a fan of using `std::pair<first, InputReader *>`, because that's not the type I want to read.  I would change your current design slightly.  Move the stream reading functions to a seperate function that takes a stream reference, and also whatever other variables you need, and have the streaming operator call that member.  This idea is commonly used when you want operators to have access to optional additional parameters

```
std::istream& loadObjectFromFile(std::istream& file, 
              first& obj,
              handler errorH=InputReader::errorHandler, 
              handler warningH=InputReader::warningHandler); //new
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& file, first& obj)
{return loadObjectFromFile(file, obj);}
```

And then to implement the reader function, is a direct copy paste, except now you also have error handlers

```
std::istream& loadObjectFromFile(std::istream& file, first& obj
                                    handler errorH, handler warningH) {
  ...
    else if (symbol == FILEPATH) 
    {
      if (!(file >> '=' >> obj.filename))
        errorH(symbol + " is incorrectly formatted.", 1); //new
    } 
    else if (symbol == SCALE) 
    {
      if (! (file >> '=' >> obj.scale) )
        errorH(symbol + " is incorrectly formatted.", 1); //new
    } 
    else 
    { //not a member: failure
      errorH(symbol + " is not a member of first.", 1); //new
      file.setstate(file.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit);
      break;
    }
  }
  return file;
}
```

Then, the corresponding change in InputReader's istream function

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& file, InputReader& obj) 
{
    ...
    else if (symbol == FIRSTTAGBEG) 
    {
      first t;
      if (loadObjectFromFile(file, obj))
        mesh.push_back(t);
    } 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& file, first& obj)` with `std::istream &InputReader::readObj(std::istream &file, first &obj)`.

Also, for consistency, replace `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& file, InputReader& obj)` with `std::istream &InputReader::readFileStream(std::istream& file)`.

Then in `readFileStream` you can write `if (readObj(file, t))`, and in `readObj` you can write 
 `errorH("oops", -1)`.